# Why is my mockito code calling the real code?

Tags: java, mockito

I am using mockito to write a test in java in intellij. I am trying to use mockito to mock an api request,
but it still seems to be calling the real code and not using the data returned from sendRequest, causing my test to fail. Why is this?
Here is the code:

```
public String sendRequest(){
       return  "1\n" +
               "2\n" +
               "3";
   }

@Test
   public void calculateWeatherCorrectly() throws IOException {
       try {
         WeatherCalculator weatherCalculator = mock(WeatherCalculator.class);
         when(weatherCalculator.sendWeatherRequest("London", "01-01-2020")).thenReturn(sendRequest());
         assertThat(midDayWeather("London", "12-01-2020"), equalTo(1.15)); 
} catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
```

Here is a smaller version of the method being tested:

```
public static Double midDayWeather(String place, String date)
            throws IOException {

        WeatherCalculator weatherCalculator = new WeatherCalculator();
        String l = weatherCalculator.sendWeatherRequest(place, date);
        String[] result = l.split("\n");
        return result.length;
        }
```

Comment: Impossible to know with that few code. Post the whole test.

Comment: I have added more code now. Does that help? Thanks.

Comment: @Chris Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: You are mocking WeatherCalculator class and intercepting sendWeatherRequest method.
Later you are asserting weatherCalculator.midDayWeather return value. It's impossible to know with the data you have shared. Share also the midDayWeather method

Comment: I have added a simple version of the midDayWeather method. I have not included the details of the method. Thank you.

Comment: And static methods cannot be mocked with Mockito.

Comment: Thank you all very much.

Comment: If I want to make the method an instance method, how can I make it work with mockito?

Answer (score 2):

You have created a mock object with the `mock()` method and set it up correctly. However, you are not using the `WeatherCalculator` object anywhere. Your method `midDayWeather()` is static and will not use your mocked `WeatherCalculator` object created in your test method. In fact, your `midDayWeather()` method creates his own `WeatherCalculator` object (which is not mocked) and use it instead.

If your static `midDayWeather()` method should work with your mocked method you have to pass it as an argument. So you method should look something like this:

```
public static Double midDayWeather(WeatherCalculator calculator,
         String place, String date) throws IOException
{
     calculator.sendWeatherRequest(...);
}
```

Then you can pass your mocked object as an argument.

Comment: Or make the method an instance method, which is likely what it should be.

Comment: If I want to make the method an instance method, how can I make it work with mockito?

Comment: @Chris Remove the `static` keyword, remove the `WeatherCalculator calculator` argument and use `this` for further calls on other methods. Then you mockito setup will kick in and return its defined value from the `thenReturn()` call instead.

Comment: Thanks. I am getting expected: 3.37, actual: null. The test is not even calling midDayWeather.

Comment: I had to use thenCallRealMethod. Thanks so much for your help.